# jQuery collapsible through toggleClass on element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an off canvas navigation menu (classname that is enabled via hover-over using jQuery on my Wordpress site. It is, as it should be, not visible on page load.

For the mobile version, I want the same nav menu to be activated by clicking on a menu icon (that I've given two classes, in this order: mobile-nav-toggle show-nav-mobile). The toggle method seems to only work for a vertical toggle. My solution to replicating the same animation on click rather than hover, is by using the toggleClass method on the icon to toggle between a classname that opens the menu nav (show-nav-mobile) and closes it (hide-nav-mobile) Using the below code:

```
jQuery(".show-nav-mobile").click(function(){
  jQuery(".offcanvasmainnav").animate({left:'0px' }, 250);
});
jQuery(".mobile-nav-toggle").click(function(){
  jQuery(".mobile-nav-toggle").toggleClass("show-nav-mobile hide-nav-mobile");
});
jQuery(".hide-nav-mobile").click(function(){
  jQuery(".offcanvasmainnav").animate({left:'-640px' }, 250);
});
```

That doesn't seem to do the job though. The jQuery opens the offcanvasmain div just fine, but doesn't close it again.

What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your element initially looks somewhat like this:

```
<nav class="mobile-nav-toggle hide-nav-mobile">...</nav>
```

This means that

a) Both these click handlers will always run when clicking, no matter if the element still has the class `hide-nav-mobile`:

```
jQuery(".mobile-nav-toggle").click(function(){
  jQuery(".mobile-nav-toggle").toggleClass("show-nav-mobile hide-nav-mobile");
});
jQuery(".hide-nav-mobile").click(function(){
  jQuery(".offcanvasmainnav").animate({left:'-640px' }, 250);
});
```

jQuery finds the element **at the moment you define the click handler**; it doesn't recheck if the element still has this class when clicking later.

b) This never attaches a click handler:

```
jQuery(".show-nav-mobile").click(function(){
  jQuery(".offcanvasmainnav").animate({left:'0px' }, 250);
});
```

because at the time of calling `jQuery(".show-nav-mobile")` it cannot find any element with that class.

To fix it, do this all in a single click handler:

```
jQuery(".mobile-nav-toggle").on('click', function(){
  const that = jQuery(this);
  that.toggleClass("show-nav-mobile hide-nav-mobile");
  jQuery(".offcanvasmainnav").animate({left: that.hasClass('show-nav-mobile') ? '0px' : '-640px' }, 250);
});
```

Comment: Wow fantastic, you were absolutely right. This solved it. Thank you.